# Making my While loop terminate with the input of "Done"

Tags: python, list, if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop

I am currently writing a program for my Intro to Programming class. The requirements are to have a user input a list of celebrity names, add them to a list, print out how many celebrities were entered, and then to print the list of the celebrities that were entered. I must use a loop, so I employed a while loop; however I cannot make it end when the user inputs `Done` to the names input field.

Below is the code, and my attempt at using an if else statement to control the loop.

```
def main():
    celebs = []

    again = 'y'

    while again == 'y':
        name = input('Enter a name: ')
        if name == 'Done':
            again == 'n'
        else:
            again == 'y'


        celebs.append(name)



    print('You entered ',len(celebs), 'celebrities to the list')
    print('   ')
    print('The ',len(celebs),'celebrities you entered were: ')

    for name in celebs:
        print(name)
main()
```

Comment: What isn't working ? at first glance it should all work - with the exception that you will add the word Done to your celeb name list. I assume that most of your code is part of your main function ?

Comment: is this the actual code? If so you need to indent everything that's meant to be in the main function, cause at the moment nothing is.

Comment: The indenting is an error posting on my part, I see now how to change that. @TonySuffolk66 how might I go about stripping the entry of done from the list?

Comment: I would avoid adding Done at all - either do the append in the else branch of your if, or break from the loop when you get the "Done"...

Comment: Thank you @TonySuffolk66, I added the append statement to the else, and all is working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the double equals to a single equals in the statements inside the if/else. You need to assign a value to 'again', but the double equals is just comparing instead.

Alternatively, you could look up the use of the 'break' statement.

Comment: I would upvote, but I do not have enough reputation. Thank you so much! I will look into 'break' as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` for comparisons and `=` for assignments. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid adding 'Done' to your list, skip to next iteration:

```
while again == 'y':
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name == 'Done':
        again = 'n'
        continue
    else:
        again = 'y'
    celebs.append(name)
```

which can be simplified to:

```
while again == 'y':
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name == 'Done':
        again = 'n'
        continue
    celebs.append(name)
```

it is also better to use `bool` value here:

```
again = True
while again:
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name == 'Done':
        again = False
        continue
    celebs.append(name)
```

or you can just use `break`:

```
while True:
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    if name.strip() == 'Done':
        break
    celebs.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If name == "Done", you should do:

```
again = 'n' # not again == 'n'
```

(Similarly for setting again = 'y', although I think that line is unnecessary, since again is already equal to 'y'.)

Comment: `raw_input` does not return trailing newline: 
`print repr(raw_input('> '))`

> foo


'foo'

Answer (score 0):

You have a comparison operator in your code instead of assignment.

Change `again == 'n'` to `again = 'n'`
and
`again == 'y'` to `again = 'y'`